# What api can I use to find the manufacturer of a system in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows VC++ Get Machine Model Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628948/windows-vc-get-machine-model-name)

I saw box.net detecting PC manufacturers and giving the users extra space in Windows 8.  Which api can I use to find out the manufacturer?

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OEMInformation  Whether that's the key used when the user creates an account is hard to guess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows VC++ Get Machine Model Name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628948/windows-vc-get-machine-model-name) and [How to get computer manufacturer and model from windows registry in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628948/windows-vc-get-machine-model-name/9630498#9630498)

Comment: @HansPassant : Thanks Hans.  I checked in my system, it is empty.  I had installed the os myself.  I guess if it was installed by Dell, this would have its information.

Comment: I guess you forgot to put your name in there ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Windows Management Instrumentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393964%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

This example is in C#, hope it works for you.

```
string manufacturer = string.Empty;
ManagementClass mc = new System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_BIOS");
ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
    {
        try
        {
            if (mo["Manufacturer"] != null) 
                 manufacturer = mo["Manufacturer"].ToString();
            break;
        }
        // Show the exception (just for test purpose)
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(manufacturer.Trim());
```

Comment: I'd go for Win32_ComputerSystem.Manufacturer instead.  The Bios is often supplied by somebody else.

Comment: @HansPassant just tried with that on my Home PC, but it is an assembled one and it returns a generic string "System manufacturer". Problably with HP,Dell or others this info is more reliable.

Comment: Naturally you have to set it. It's not like the computer is magically going to return "Steve".